# Javascript preventDefault not working, says event is undefined

Tags: javascript, html, input

My code is like this:

```
        var search = document.getElementById("search");
        var searchForm = document.getElementById("searchForm");

        searchForm.onSubmit = function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            console.log("BLBLBL");
            var contenders = [];
            var searchValue = search.value;
            for (var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
                for (var j = 0; j < searchValue.length; j++) {
                    if (searchValue[j] === cards[i][j]) {
                        contenders.push(cards[i]);
                    } else {
                        delete cards[i];
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            console.log(contenders);
        }
```

In an HTML file with this form:

```
<form id="searchForm">
        <input id="search"></input>
</form>
```

When I run the code in an HTML page, it says:

```
buyPokemonCardSearch.html:30 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined
at HTMLFormElement.searchForm.onSubmit (buyPokemonCardSearch.html:30)
at <anonymous>:1:12
```

[It's a fake website, so don't judge]
Why doesn't it work? The console.log's are there because I wanted to detect where my code went wrong.

Comment: I don't know how you get to run that function, because the correct property is `.onsubmit`.

Comment: You didn't post the code where you are submitting the code. And i would strongly advice against those `.on`-events... use `addEventListener` instead

Comment: no, it's like a search. Anyways, the reason it didn't work is because it's `.onsubmit`, not `.onSubmit`.